# Use CSS styles file in Freemarker without <mvc:resources/> tag

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I wonder whether it is possible to add **CSS file** to my **index.ftl** if no `<mvc:resources/>` tag is specified?
I am sure there is the way to do it, but can't find the answer how.. probably using **classpath:**?

lets consider following, sample project:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I guest that it's an FTL is irrelevant. At least as far as you don't yet have a URL where you could visit that CSS directly with a browser.

Comment: I supposed so, but still dont know how to do it without the mvcresources, there must be some path that will fit

Answer (score 0):

it will be accessible without the  tag actually depends on how you have configured the MVC configuration in web.xml. i mean to say that what URL pattern is specified for Spring servlet in web.xml.

if /* then you will have to use , otherwise you can access the files outside WEB-INF.

Comment: if /* then I have to use what ?:P I suppose you didnt finish your sentence

Comment: With /* all the URLs will go to spring so u have to use resources tag to specify location path. 


Suppose u have defined /spriuung in web.XML then you can try to access CSS directly on web server paths.